# Rcpp "no such symbol" in shared library, but symbol certainly exists

Tags: c++, r, shared-libraries, rcpp, r-package

I am building a complex R package using Rcpp that integrates C++ with a large external library (I'll call it `my_lib`), which itself is dependent on several C++ libraries. I've built all of the external dependencies as static libraries, and am attempting to use `RCPP_MODULE` to expose a class from `my_lib` to R. I've done everything I can to ensure that the package is structured correctly, but in what I believe to be the loading phase of the package, *after* `my_package.so` has been created and is non-empty, I'm told that a symbol does not exist in my package. However, I can verify that the symbol *certainly* does exist in the shared library that was compiled and linked successfully.

First, my `Makevars` file is not trivial, so I will post that here. I assume that this file is not perfect, but it seems to be doing its job. Any corrections to this file that are unrelated to the problem I will describe are appreciated but secondary.

`Makevars`:

```
$(info The name of the shared library to be created is: $(SHLIB))

DEPENDENCY_DIRS = -L../lib/cpp-dependencies/local/abseil/lib \
    -L../lib/cpp-dependencies/local/cares/lib \
    -L../lib/cpp-dependencies/local/gflags/lib \
    -L../lib/cpp-dependencies/local/grpc/lib \
    -L../lib/cpp-dependencies/local/immer/lib \
    -L../lib/cpp-dependencies/local/protobuf/lib \
    -L../lib/cpp-dependencies/local/re2/lib \
    -L../lib/cpp-dependencies/local/zlib/lib


DEPENDENCY_LIBS = -lclient -lprotobufd \
    ../lib/cpp-dependencies/local/arrow/lib/libarrow_flight.a \
    ../lib/cpp-dependencies/local/arrow/lib/libarrow.a \
    ../lib/cpp-dependencies/local/arrow/lib/libarrow_bundled_dependencies.a \
    -lgrpc++ -lgrpc -laddress_sorting -lgpr -lupb -labsl_raw_hash_set -labsl_hashtablez_sampler -labsl_exponential_biased -labsl_hash -labsl_city \
    -labsl_wyhash -labsl_statusor -labsl_bad_variant_access -lgpr -lupb \
    -labsl_status -labsl_random_distributions -labsl_random_seed_sequences -labsl_random_internal_pool_urbg -labsl_random_internal_randen \
    -labsl_random_internal_randen_hwaes -labsl_random_internal_randen_hwaes_impl -labsl_random_internal_randen_slow -labsl_random_internal_platform \
    -labsl_random_internal_seed_material -labsl_random_seed_gen_exception -labsl_cord -labsl_bad_optional_access -labsl_str_format_internal \
    -labsl_synchronization -labsl_stacktrace -labsl_symbolize -labsl_debugging_internal -labsl_demangle_internal -labsl_graphcycles_internal \
    -labsl_malloc_internal -labsl_time -labsl_strings -labsl_throw_delegate -labsl_int128 -labsl_strings_internal -labsl_base -labsl_raw_logging_internal \
    -labsl_log_severity -labsl_spinlock_wait -labsl_civil_time -labsl_time_zone -lssl -lre2 -lcares


# tells the compiler where to look for additional include directories
PKG_CXXFLAGS = -I"../lib/cpp-client/my_lib/client/include/public" \
    -I"../lib/cpp-client/my_lib/core/include/public" \
    -I"/usr/share/R/include" \
    -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include"

# list of required libraries, including my_lib and associated dependencies
PKG_LIBS = $(LAPACK_LIBS) \
    $(BLAS_LIBS) \
    $(FLIBS) \
    $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS) \
    $(R_CPPFLAGS) \
    -L"/usr/lib/R/lib" -lR \
    $(R_CXXFLAGS) \
    $(DEPENDENCY_DIRS) \
    $(DEPENDENCY_LIBS) \
    -L"../lib/cpp-client/my_lib/build/client/core_dir" -lcore \
    -L"../lib/cpp-client/my_lib/build/client" -lclient

CC = `"${R_HOME}/bin/R" CMD config CC`
CFLAGS = `"${R_HOME}/bin/R" CMD config CFLAGS`
CXX17 = `"${R_HOME}/bin/R" CMD config CXX17`
CXX17STD=`"${R_HOME}/bin/R" CMD config CXX17STD`
CXXFLAGS = `"${R_HOME}/bin/R" CMD config CXX17FLAGS`

# set C++ standard
CXX_STD = CXX17
# all src directory c++ source files
SOURCES = $(wildcard *.cpp)
# compiled objects to link
OBJECTS = $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)

all: $(SHLIB)
```

It is worth noting that `my_lib` and all of its dependencies were compiled and archived *separately*, and all of the necessary static libraries have already been built once I get to this point. This is not an option for portability, but I'm just trying to get things off the ground on my local machine.

After running `install.packages()` I get the usual startup messages and ensuing compiler calls for my `src` files, which result in `.o` files for each C++ file in `src` and a (large, 250M) `my_package.so` file stored in `src`. Here is the output of that process for completeness (with spaces for readability), from a clean environment:

```
> install.packages("/home/user/my_package", repos=NULL, type="source")
Installing package into ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
* installing *source* package ‘my_package’ ...
** using staged installation
** libs
using C++ compiler: ‘g++ (Ubuntu 9.4.0-1ubuntu1~20.04.1) 9.4.0’
using C++17
The name of the shared library to be created is: my_package.so
g++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include'    -I"../lib/cpp-client/my_lib/client/include/public" -I"../lib/cpp-client/my_lib/core/include/public" -I"/usr/share/R/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -c rcpp_hello_world.cpp -o rcpp_hello_world.o
g++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include'    -I"../lib/cpp-client/my_lib/client/include/public" -I"../lib/cpp-client/my_lib/core/include/public" -I"/usr/share/R/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -c RcppExports.cpp -o RcppExports.o
g++ -std=gnu++17 -I"/usr/share/R/include" -DNDEBUG  -I'/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include'    -I"../lib/cpp-client/my_lib/client/include/public" -I"../lib/cpp-client/my_lib/core/include/public" -I"/usr/share/R/include" -I"/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/Rcpp/include" -fpic  -g -O2 -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/r-base-dIDxrQ/r-base-4.3.0=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2  -c client_caller.cpp -o client_caller.o
g++ -std=gnu++17 -shared -L/usr/lib/R/lib -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -o rdeephaven.so rcpp_hello_world.o RcppExports.o client_caller.o -llapack -lblas -lgfortran -lm -lquadmath -fopenmp -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR -L../lib/cpp-dependencies/local/abseil/lib -L../lib/cpp-dependencies/local/cares/lib -L../lib/cpp-dependencies/local/gflags/lib -L../lib/cpp-dependencies/local/grpc/lib -L../lib/cpp-dependencies/local/immer/lib -L../lib/cpp-dependencies/local/protobuf/lib -L../lib/cpp-dependencies/local/re2/lib -L../lib/cpp-dependencies/local/zlib/lib -lclient -lprotobufd ../lib/cpp-dependencies/local/arrow/lib/libarrow_flight.a ../lib/cpp-dependencies/local/arrow/lib/libarrow.a ../lib/cpp-dependencies/local/arrow/lib/libarrow_bundled_dependencies.a -lgrpc++ -lgrpc -laddress_sorting -lgpr -lupb -labsl_raw_hash_set -labsl_hashtablez_sampler -labsl_exponential_biased -labsl_hash -labsl_city -labsl_wyhash -labsl_statusor -labsl_bad_variant_access -lgpr -lupb -labsl_status -labsl_random_distributions -labsl_random_seed_sequences -labsl_random_internal_pool_urbg -labsl_random_internal_randen -labsl_random_internal_randen_hwaes -labsl_random_internal_randen_hwaes_impl -labsl_random_internal_randen_slow -labsl_random_internal_platform -labsl_random_internal_seed_material -labsl_random_seed_gen_exception -labsl_cord -labsl_bad_optional_access -labsl_str_format_internal -labsl_synchronization -labsl_stacktrace -labsl_symbolize -labsl_debugging_internal -labsl_demangle_internal -labsl_graphcycles_internal -labsl_malloc_internal -labsl_time -labsl_strings -labsl_throw_delegate -labsl_int128 -labsl_strings_internal -labsl_base -labsl_raw_logging_internal -labsl_log_severity -labsl_spinlock_wait -labsl_civil_time -labsl_time_zone -lssl -lre2 -lcares -L../lib/cpp-client/my_lib/build/client/core_dir -lcore -L../lib/cpp-client/my_lib/build/client -lclient -L/usr/lib/R/lib -lR
installing to /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/00LOCK-my_package/00new/my_package/libs
** R
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
** help
*** installing help indices
** building package indices
** testing if installed package can be loaded from temporary location
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘my_package’ in .doLoadActions(where, attach):
 error in load action .__A__.1 for package my_package: Rcpp::loadModule(module = "ClientCaller", what = TRUE, env = ns, : Unable to load module "ClientCaller": Failed to initialize module pointer: Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...): no such symbol _rcpp_module_boot_ClientCaller in package my_package

Error: loading failed
Execution halted
ERROR: loading failed
* removing ‘/usr/local/lib/R/site-library/my_package’
Warning message:
In install.packages("/home/user/my_package", repos = NULL, type = "source") :
  installation of package ‘/home/user/my_package’ had non-zero exit status
```

Naturally, it sounds like _rcpp_module_boot_ClientCaller does not exist in `my_package.so`, and that is what the loader is complaining about. However, a call to `nm` reveals that the symbol *does exist and is resolved* in `my_package.so`:

```
root@docker-desktop:/home/user/my_package/src# nm my_package.so | grep _rcpp_module_boot_ClientCaller
0000000001ad3c50 T _rcpp_module_boot_ClientCaller
0000000001acf3af t _rcpp_module_boot_ClientCaller.cold
```

This has totally stumped me. I've ensured that all of my spelling of `ClientCaller` around the package is correct, and have done all I can to format the package correctly. Here are some additional files for your verification:

`exports.R`:

```
#' @import Rcpp
#' @export Client

Rcpp::loadModule("ClientCaller", TRUE)
```

`package.R`:

```
#' @useDynLib my_package, .registration = TRUE
#' @import methods Rcpp
"_PACKAGE"
```

`client_caller.cpp`:

```
#include "my_lib/client/client.h"
#include <Rcpp.h>

namespace Rcpp {

RCPP_MODULE(ClientCaller) {
  class_<my_lib::client::Client>("Client")
  .constructor()
  ;
}

}
```

`DESCRIPTION`:

```
Package: my_package
Type: Package
Title: What the Package Does in One 'Title Case' Line
Version: 1.0
Date: 2023-05-12
Author: Your Name
Maintainer: Your Name <your@email.com>
Description: One paragraph description of what the package does as one or more full sentences.
License: GPL (>= 2)
Depends: Rcpp (>= 1.0.10)
Imports: Rcpp (>= 1.0.10)
LinkingTo: Rcpp (>= 1.0.10)
```

`NAMESPACE`:

```
useDynLib(my_package, .registration=TRUE)
importFrom(Rcpp, evalCpp)
exportPattern("^[[:alpha:]]+")
```

I do not know what else to verify, or what could possibly be the source of this problem. Any help here is appreciated, as I am at wits end.

Finally, I am running an image of Ubuntu 20.04 on Docker Desktop for an isolated environment. All of the files are stored on my local machine, and are exposed to Docker via a mounted volume.

Comment: Hi Alex and welcome to StackOverflow, and Rcpp.  I would at this point recommend to simplify and work on smaller test repos to work out details. I think what you have here is a combination of large and complicated external build (hello, abseil!) which you seem to have under control _plus_ a use of Rcpp Modules.  There are a few small details that have to be right to instantiate Modules so maybe (just a guess?) that is off.  I'd create a new package with a trivial `struct` or `class` used by a Module and ensure the module loads.  Or equally look at an existing Module's using package and check.

Comment: Hey @DirkEddelbuettel, thanks for the quick response. I've done exactly this, I substituted a simple header and implementation class for the complicated class, exposed it via Rcpp module, built, and everything worked perfectly. I did this both in a clean test package, and in this package without referencing the actual external library I want to use. It seems there is something in the details of how the external library is talking with Rcpp that is causing load issues. The mystery is that the symbol exists and is resolved, but cannot be found. That gives me little to work with.

Comment: Good thinking :)  Can you go the other way and take out / disable that Modules bit for a second to see if things work?  Sometimes messages shadow the underlying issue.  Then again as you know these things are both somewhat mechanical and do work.  But the devil is as always hiding in the considerable detail ...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I just ran this experiment and found no problems, package build and installed just fine. I only removed the Rcpp module glue code, the roxygen export tag for Client, and the Rcpp::LoadModule() call for loading ClientModule.

Comment: Scratching my chin and coming up empty for reasons why Modules may throw a spanner.  _Maybe_ because something in src/init.c (or whereever that code sits for you, could be `Rcpp::compileAttributes()` generated).  Have _vague_ recollection of that having annoyed me before too.  So maybe ... if it works without Modules stay without Modules.  Rcpp::XPtr can do similar things more flexibly...

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I was thinking of going the no-modules route as a last ditch effort. I guess I may not have a choice. I suppose I'll leave this up in case anyone else comes up with a solution / explanation at some point.

Comment: In all seriousness there may be a micro-bug here. But we'd need a baby-sized (public !!) version of your repo to make things whole and look more close.  A _minimally complete verifiable example_ having the attributes you have: external libraries (singular for test case) and a simple Modules use.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel I will see what I can do to create a small example to get to you. At the moment I have to prioritize writing glue code, but I should be able to get you something usable sometime soon.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Naturally, the solution was super simple and the problem was user error. I had it in my head that `Rcpp::compileAttributes()` was getting called every time `install.packages()` or `R CMD INSTALL` got called - it appears that is not the case. My `RcppExports.R` had leftover crap that the loader was looking for because I never recompiled the attributes when I updated the interface. I guess I brushed over that in the vignette. Go figure.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, `install.packages()` or `R CMD INSTALL` ***do not*** call `Rcpp::compileAttributes()` if you're not using `devtools` or RStudio as I'm not. This is made explicit [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Rcpp/vignettes/Rcpp-attributes.pdf), on the second paragraph of page 5.

I was under the impression that `compileAttributes()` got called automatically by any install function, so I failed to recompile the attributes myself, which left `RcppExports.R` holding a symbol that the loader did not know what to do with.

If you are not using RStudio or `devtools` for package install, be sure to recompile the Rcpp attributes *any time you edit the interface* before reinstalling. Or, of course, read the vignettes more carefully.

Comment: IIRC if you build an Rcpp-using package in RStudio, it knows this and does it for you.  Otherwise it is indeed up to you.  And it's been like that for over a decade.  I presume one could add a simple rules to `src/Makevars` to regenerate `R/RcppExports.R` and `src/RcppExports.cpp` each time a source file changes.  But I am not sure that has been done before.  In any event, glad that you are cooking with gas now.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel Yep, super simple detail I overlooked. I'm using VSCode in a dev container for development, which RStudio does not have great support for. I've not thought of having `Makevars` handle that, that isn't a bad idea. Thanks for your quick responses and all your help. Cheers!

Comment: I am glad you got your (fairly complex) project working -- which is good because you clearly laid it out cleanly.  But sometimes one need to walk before one can run as the devil is indeed often in the details.

Comment: That's certainly what I'm learning. Hopefully smooth sailing from here!